# How to use / replace env variable in Svelte component locally

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, svelte, rollupjs, svelte-3

I'm searching for the missing piece around `.env` files in Svelte. I use an env file for local dev only, like this:

```
GRAPHQL_URL=http://localhost:8010/proxy/graphql
```

In `rollup.config.js` I wanna replace the env variable into a string which I can use in a Svelte component (using `@Rollup/plugin-replace`):

```js
export default [{
...
    plugins: [
    replace({
      preventAssignment: true,
      GRAPHQL_URL: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL
    })
...
```

With that I would expect to have a variable `GRAPHQL_URL` injected into the bundle and available in a svelte file? Like this:

`mycomponent.svelte`:

```
const url = GRAPHQL_URL;
console.log(url); // expect "http://localhost:8010/proxy/graphql"
```

But I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at instanceOf.mjs:11
    at web.js:160
```

I develop with `npm run dev` containing `rollup -c -w`. Node version 16 and NPM version 7.

I tried out some [`dotenv` guides](https://medium.com/dev-cafe/how-to-setup-env-variables-to-your-svelte-js-app-c1579430f032) without success.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stringify your variable, as opposed to injecting process itself:

```
GRAPHQL_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.GRAPHQL_URL)
```